# Запустить метод при создании экземпляра

Tags: c#

Есть класс `A`

```
partial class A { 
  public event EventHandler MyHandler;
  public A() { };
}

partial class A { 
  protected void H1(object sender, EventArgs e) { Something1(); };
  protected void B1() { MyHandler += H1; }
}

partial class A { 
  protected void H2(object sender, EventArgs e) { Something2(); };
  protected void B2() { MyHandler += H2; }
}

partial class A { 
  protected void H3(object sender, EventArgs e) { Something3(); };
  protected void B3() { MyHandler += H3; }
}
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы разделяемый класс вызывал метод `B[N]` в конструкторе, при этом не меняя первое определение. Поясню, у меня есть куча файлов `cs`, каждый из них определяет логику поведения экземпляра, подключая их и отключая - класс `A` ведёт себя по разному. Иногда нужно чтобы модуль подключался к событиям этого класса при его создании. Как это сделать?

Как решал проблему: Как вариант использовал атрибут

```
public class AutoInitialize : Attribute { }
```

и в методы добавлять атрибут

```
[AutoInitialize]
public void B1() { }
[AutoInitialize]
public void B2() { }
[AutoInitialize]
public void B3() { }
```

а в основной конструктор вставляем текст

```
  MethodInfo[] methods = GetType()
    .GetMethods()
    .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(AutoInitialize)) != null && !x.IsStatic).ToArray();
  foreach (MethodInfo method in methods)
  {
    method.Invoke(this, new object[0]);
    /* try { method.Invoke(this, new object[0]); } catch { } */
  }
```

Comment: А как в конструкторе `A` выясняется какой метод добавить в обработчик события (то есть какой из `BN` вызвать)?

Comment: Эти паршал классы хоть связаны друг с другом? Может будет правильней их разделить?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то вашему классу нужно расширяемое поведение. Почему нельзя выделить для этого интерфейс вида `IFoo { void B(); }` и создать набор реализаций этого интерфейса `A1`, `A2`, `A3` и т.д.? Потом нужно будет собрать реализации в кучу и вызвать для каждой из них метод `B`.

Comment: @AGS17 по факту я подписываюсь на события и делаю что-то внутри, они и так разделены по файлам, подключая эти файлы в проект я получаю дополнительные методы и свойства, а также хочу подписаться на определенные события при создании экземпляра.

Comment: @Vlad не понимаю, я должен знать изначально какие методы я вызываю в patial классе? Я как раз хочу от этого уйти и подключать/отключать partial определения.

Comment: @Regent например все методы начинающиеся с определенного набора букв, если есть другие способы, то я хотел бы их услышать.

Comment: Я не очень понял, как вы от этого уходите? В вашем примере вы точно знаете, что partial классы предоставляют методы, которые начинаются с `InitA_`.

Comment: @Vlad совершенно верно, я создаю методы, которые смогу отследить в основном определении класса, а в вспомогательных определениях называю их соответственно, это единственное решение проблемы, которое я смог придумать. Подключая `cs` файлы класса с методом `InitA_блаблабла` основное определение его находит и запускает, причем я не меняю основное определение класса. Есть ли более элегантное решение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В комментариях объяснить свою точку зрения не удалось, поэтому описываю здесь.

Я вижу решение следующим образом.

1. Создаем интерфейс, метод которого будет использован при инициализации.

   ```
   interface IInitializer
   {
       void Initialize(IA a); // аналог методов B1, B2, B3
   }

   // нужен для доступа к членам класса A
   interface IA
   {
       event EventHandler MyHandler;
   }
   ```
2. Создаем реализации.

   ```
   class Initializer1 : IInitializer
   {
       public B(IA a)
       {
           a.MyHandler += (s, e) => Something1();
       }
   }

   class Initializer2 : IInitializer { ... }
   ```
3. Вызываем метод для всех реализаций.

   ```
   class A : IA
   {
       public A()
       {
           var initializers = new IInitializer[] { new Initializer1(), new Initializer2(), ... }
           foreach (var i in initializers)
           {
               i.Initialize(this);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Насколько я понимаю, вас смущает необходимость перечислять все инициализаторы в классе `A`. Т.е. при создании нового инициализатора придется менять класс `A`. Для того, чтобы избежать этого можно воспользоваться каким-нибудь контейнером. Например, [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

Рассмотрим пример с MEF. Сначала пометим реализации атрибутом `Export`:

```
[Export(typeof(IInitializer))]
class Initializer1 : IInitializer { ... }

[Export(typeof(IInitializer))]
class Initializer2 : IInitializer { ... }
```

Потом подправим класс `A`:

```
    class A : IA
    {
        public A()
        {
            // Выбор каталога зависит от ваших нужд. В данном случае предполагается, что все реализации лежат в этой же сборке.
            using (var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(GetType().Assembly))
            using (var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog))
            {
                var initializers = container.GetExportedValues<IInitializer>();
                foreach ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Писал без VS, так что за компилируемость не ручаюсь.

Comment: Да я хочу обойти проблему изменения конструктора класса. Но как мне в контейнер `var initializers` добавить метод из partial определения? по ссылке решения не нашел, или не понял.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, обновил ответ.

Comment: т.е. по факту это тот же `System.Reflection` только с боку? и если этих классов у меня, допустим, 5 то я и интерфейсов тоже 5 должен создать?

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, условно говоря - да. Зачем 5 интерфейсов? У меня в примере один интерфейс и несколько классов.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, ваши примеры с Reflection требуют при добавлении нового partial класса наличия знаний о сигнатурах методов, об их наименованиях. Кроме того, реализации никак не инкапсулированы и могут дергать методы из других классов, что приведет к совершенно адовым зависимостям.

Comment: эммм... почему же? GetType().GetMethods() берет только методы данного класса, и потом я фильтрую по аттрибуту, посмотрите вариант решения в PS2

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61920/discussion-between-vlad-and--).

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - можно через [директивы препроцессора](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/) включать/выключать куски кода:

```
#define PART1
//#define PART2
#define PART3

partial class A { 
  public event EventHandler MyHandler;
  public A() {
#if PART1
    B1();
#endif
#if PART2
    B2();
#endif
#if PART3
    B3();
#endif
  }
}

#if PART1
partial class A { 
  protected void H1(object sender, EventArgs e) { Something1(); };
  protected void B1() { MyHandler += H1; }
}
#endif

#if PART2
partial class A { 
  protected void H2(object sender, EventArgs e) { Something2(); };
  protected void B2() { MyHandler += H2; }
}
#endif

#if PART3
partial class A { 
  protected void H3(object sender, EventArgs e) { Something3(); };
  protected void B3() { MyHandler += H3; }
}
#endif
```

Comment: при добавлении нового partial файлика мне нужно будет менять и основной конструктор, причем еще и не забывать вносить директивы в свойство проекта, это тоже не удобно, но спасибо за вариант.