# Реально ли разделить partial класс на 2 библиотеки

Tags: c#

Собственно вопрос в теме.
Есть `dll` с классом `A`

```
public partial class A: SubA, ISomethingInterface
{
  ...
}
```

Реально ли дополнить его, подключив другую `dll`?

```
public partial class A
{
  public void NewMethod() { }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Из [документации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx):

> All partial-type definitions meant to be parts
>   of the same type must be defined in the
>   same assembly and the same module (.exe
>   or .dll file). Partial definitions cannot span
>   multiple modules.

Вольный перевод:

Все объявления частичных классов означают один тип и должны быть объявлены в одной и той же сборке и модуле. Частичные объявления нельзя разбить на несколько модулей.

Comment: Ясно и доходчиво, будем искать другие пути решения.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, а вы ту же задачу решаете? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/690284/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: Неа, просто стало интересно. Запрос в Гугл и на английском SO нашел похожий вопрос) Вот ссылка если что https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858649/partial-classes-in-separate-dlls

Comment: Да, но проблема немного другая уже... Там необходимо было вызвать методы и всё было внутри одного dll, теперь же я работаю с Windows в WPF дополняя ресурсы новыми стилями в зависимости от подключенных dll.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, плагины хотите сделать? Так тот же MEF в помощь: DirectoryCatalog - и вперед.

Comment: @Vlad видимо придётся...

Answer (score 5):

Частичные классы - это фича языка C#, а не рантайма. В бинарных файлах класс уже не может быть разбит на два фрагмента, поэтому все объявления собираются вместе при компиляции.

Соответственно, в двух разных библиотеках класс одновременно оказаться не может.

Answer (score 1):

Если коротко, ответ - нет, нельзя. При компиляции, он в любом случае компилируется в один класс и при его вызове будет создаваться всего один объект класс.
Если вам необходимо дополнить класс, как в вашем примере, я рекомендую использовать расширение класса A статическим классом. А именно:

```
public partial class A: SubA, ISomethingInterface
{
  ...
}

public static class AHerlper
{
    public static void NewMethod(this A) { }
}
```

После этого вы сможете вызывать этот самый NewMethod на экземплярах класса A.

```
A a = new A();
a.NewMethod();
```